# VB - Access a control created with code

Tags: vb.net

So if I create a `PictureBox` with the code...

```
    Dim the_pic As New PictureBox
    With the_pic
        .Name = "pic"
        .Size = New Size(30, 100)
        .Location = New Point(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 - 50)
        .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        .BackColor = Color.White
    End With
    Me.Controls.Add(the_pic)
```

...How do I access the methods and properties of the created `PictureBox`? Because it is created in code, I can't program directly to it. If I do `pic.*` it doesn't know that pic even exists, because its created at runtime. How do I account for this? All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it doesn't know that pic even exists, because its created at runtime

That's not quite correct.

Actually, it doesn't know that `the_pic` exists because it's a **local variable**.
The variable is not visible outside the function it's defined in.

If you make it a field in the class, it will be visible everywhere in the class.
If you want to have more than one of them, you should use a `List(Of PictureBox)`.

Note that the `Name` property is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the name you declared for it: `the_pic`, that is its programmatic name.

If you look at the .designer.vb file, you will see that that is what the designer does behind the scenes when you add a control graphically.

You also need to declare `the_pic` globally and `WithEvents`, as in `Private WithEvents the_pic as PictureBox`
If you do not declare it `WithEvents`, you won't be able to hook up to any of its events.